# Warptangent and simple wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

If I'm not running a node and all I want to do is open simple wallet to check my balance, do I need to download the latest version of Monero?

Comment: Thanks for the response - it was a badly-worded question. I am running 9.4 so I take it I shouldn't have a problem checking my balance. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the wording of your question it is not clear if you sometimes run your own node (when checking your balance) or if you never run a node and check your balance with another method (connecting to a remote node or using a view key tool available online).

If you are running 0.9.4 and all you want to do is check your balance then there is no urgency to update to 0.10.0.

If you are running a Monero version prior to 0.9.4 you should [update](https://getmonero.org/downloads/) now.